# Pass data to encapsulated javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my webapp I have a variable like this

```
var data = {
     getItem: function(key){
         ...
     }
}
```

In all of my scripts I can use

```
data.getItem("Test");
```

But how can I use it in `jquery plugins`? Plugins often have following structure

```
(function($, window, document) {   
     //....plugin-code
});
```

How do I call this kind of structure? Is it possible to use my global data variable in such plugins?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible (unless the `data` identifier has been overshadowed by a more local variable/argument in the plug-in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data variable is global, then yes you can use it anywhere, including inside jQuery plugins.

You'll need to make sure that data is defined before any self-executing functions that are going to use it.

Comment: "immediately invoked" instead of "self-executing"

Comment: @Sime Interesting technical point. Thanks.

More info here, for those interested:
http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Answer (score 1):

Actually they tend to have structure

```
(function($) {   
    // plugin-code
})(jQuery);
```

the points being that

1. they can assume that $ in this scope will always be jQuery, regardless of anything else loaded that defines $ e.g. prototype
2. everything is defined inside this closure and so only what you choose to expose (by `$.fn` or `$.extend`) is leaked out to the outside world

Obviously if it's just your plugin in your environment where you can assume you're always running $ = jQuery then you don't need these. (Yours also has document and window: I've never seen these overridden and I'm not sure what you'd pass in as arguments here other than document and window themselves?)

Were you asking about defining data inside the plugin or pulling it in from outside the plugin scope? There's no restrictions of what you can write inside, so if you define and use it inside then your code will work exactly as befoer. If you need to access data defined inside from the outside then you'll need to leak it out somehow, e.g. adding an accessor method to one of $, document or window.

If you're pulling in data from outside the plugin scope then you can still access global variables from inside your closure, or you could pass it in as an extra argument - I don't think it'd make any difference.